# Is it possible to disable some page content, depending on PivotItem selection

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, pivot

I know that i can hide anything in codebehind, in selectionchanged event handler. But is it possible to, lets say, to have 2 PivotItems and one control outside of pivot, and hide that control, when 1st PivotItem is selected in xaml?
Worked, thanks to @Josh Earl, using the converter:

```
 public class PivotIndexToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
        {
            int index = (int)value;
            return index == 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
        {
            Visibility visibility = ( Visibility )value;
            return visibility == Visibility.Visible ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think its possible to do this directly. You could get pretty close, though, if you databound your `Visibility` property to the `PivotItem.SelectedItem` property. You'd need to create a simple `ValueConverter` to translate your `PivotItem` index to a `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Visible` as appropriate.

Here's a [good intro to `ValueConverter`](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx).